# How to solve this ? this error occurs on Appium server

Tags: android, appium

Hi Friends can anyone help me how to solve this issue ?( appium server)

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)     at Chromedriver.callee$2$0$ (C:\Users\Sample\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:176:15)

I'm using Android 2.2 , and the emulator details are 
platformVersion: '5.1',
deviceName: 'Android Emulator',
app: 'C:\Users\Sample\Downloads\PaySign.apk',
avd: 'Test5.1',
autoWebview: true

when I run a Sample.js on Node cmd , it says , throw new error('session did not start properly' +error);

And on Appium - [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)     at Chromedriver.callee$2$0$ (C:\Users\Sample\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:176:15)

Thanks and Regards,
Manasa

Comment: You have mentioned Android 2.2 but platformversion 5.1. What are you trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Santhosh , I was using Android studio 2.2 , and thanks, I solved it :) !  Regards,

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I uninstalled the emulator and re-installed it , i restarted my system it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Appium doesn’t perform testing on mobile devices support Android Version lower than 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you faced is clear from stacktrace:

`Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520`

[With each update to Chromedriver there is an increase in the minimum supported version of Chrome](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md), so you have several options:

1. Get new emulator with Chrome version 55+ and it should work!
2. Check Chrome version you have on current emulator and download compatible version of chromedriver. In session capabilities just add 1 line:

`caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "/abs/path/to/chromedriver.exe")`

It should work as well!